# Manipulate aggregate data in usable way in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my results which I get from aggregation in mongodb.

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "date" : "2013-07-01",
            "ncs" : "subscription",

        },
        "traffic" : 1
    }
         ]
```

But I need to get data like following

```
    {

            "date" : "2013-07-01",
            "ncs" : "subscription",
            "traffic" : 1
    }
```

Are there any way to achieve this through **$project** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, try this:

{$project:{"_id":0, "date":"$_id.date", "ncs":"$_id.ncs", "traffic":1}}